# Basement Drain Pump pipe vibrates

Tags: plumbing, water

Outflow pipe rattles and vibrates when water is discharged.  Is something wrong with the pump?  Just started doing it.  Believe it is a 404 liberty pump.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Was the manufacturers install instructions followed 101%? Some things that may look not necessary or even makes no sense can be causing such problems

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the pump from it's location and take it to a work area. remove the inlet screen and clear out the debris on the impeller. Also check the impeller for any bent or broken vanes. If there are any missing vanes you will need to replace it or the whole pump. Test run the pump for a couple seconds to see if the vibration has been eliminated. If it has, Reinstall in the sump and put back into operation.